# Is it possible to cancel while I was waiting without changing the meaning of the sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It took a long time, but at last it arrived. Note that the seller explained (while I was waiting) why it was taking so long

Would it be possible to cancel why I was waiting . In this case do we understand that the explanation came while I was waiting

Comment: @JamesK You are probably. correct that “cancel” was used instead of “omit.” I shall delete my comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of *why it was taking so long* implies that the explanation was during that time. If the explanation had been after it was delivered, you would expect *why it took/had taken so long*.

Comment: Would it possible to write  "It took a long time, but at last it arrived. Note that the seller explained (while I was waiting) why it took so long" because took  past simple  implies that I received what I had waited for ,so at this time , I was not waiting any more

Comment: Yes, you can certainly say that. Once more: the choice of aspectual expressions (continuous vs simple, or perfect vs non-perfect) is usually a choice that the speaker/writer can make depending on how they are choosing to present the events, **not** a choice forced by the objective circumstances. "It took a long time, but at last it arrived" is quite natural, because there is no need to present the time waiting for delivery as extended. But your original example locates something temporally within that period, so it is natural to present the delivery as a continuing process.

Comment: What do you think to use " had explained " instead of "explained", is Past Perfect  mandatory in this case. I think  that it is not necessary because the explaination is located while I was waiting so obviously before I received the item

Comment: Past perfect is rarely mandatory, but sometimes it can be confusing if it is not used. Here I think the temporal relationships are obvious, so it is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do have to put "while I was waiting" in order to make the meaning of your sentences clear. You can also consider re-writing the second sentence to give it even  more clarity:

It took a long time, but at last it arrived. While I was waiting, the seller explained why it was taking so long.